# Create Email Notification function for Gravity Forms Product Add-ons Plugin

Tags: woocommerce, add-on, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using the Gravity Forms Product Add-ons plugin for WooCommerce. Woo confirms that the Admin Notification email isn't a feature when the form is used on a product:

**"Gravity Forms Add-Ons does not send email notifications when they are assigned to a product."** (see FAQs: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-gravity-forms-product-addons/)

While I understand that it seems redundant given the form fields are all included in the WooCommerce email confirmations, the form I'm adding to my products is quite comprehensive and I'd prefer to keep all that messy extra data separate to the WooCommerce order transaction by having the usual Gravity Forms Admin Notification send via email also (I plan to remove the add-on fields from the WooCommerce emails).

Can anyone give me guidance on how to get the usual Gravity Forms Admin Notification email to send even when the form is assigned to a product, please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Any chance I can get some help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The WC GF Product Add-ons plugin disables the notifications via Gravity Forms' "gform_disable_notifications_{form-id}" filter. You *should* be able to remove it like so:

```
if( isset( $woocommerce_gravityforms ) ) {
    add_filter( 'gform_disable_notification', function( $disable, $notification, $form ) {
        remove_filter( 'gform_disable_notification_' . $form['id'], array( $woocommerce_gravityforms, 'disable_notifications'), 10, 3 );
    }, 10, 3 );
}
```

This would enable notifications for **all** forms attached to products. If you want to enable notifications for a specific form, you could simply use this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_disable_notification_#', '__return_false' );
```

Replace "#" with the ID of your form.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and guidance. While those pieces of code didn't work specifically, it did help guide me towards what I needed to do. 

I looked up the Gravity knowledgebase and familiarised myself with the various "disable" functions and was able to find the place in the add-on plugin where the emails were being disabled. 

For future reference, this is what worked: 

`function disable_notifications( $disabled, $form, $lead ) {
   return true;}`

I changed "true" to "false" and the admin notification began sending. 

Much gratitude!

Comment: I am having the same issue, but adding this code below did NOT help. I am probably doing it wrong though since I have limited understanding on how this works. Can you provide more specifics as to what you used and how?
Thanks!
Here is what did NOT work:  `add_filter( 'gform_disable_notification_2', 'disable_notification', 10, 4 );
    function disable_notification( $is_disabled, $notification, $form, $entry ) {
        return false;
    }`